# Java - How to assign a list of values to a repeated protobuf field without for loop?

Tags: java, syntax, protocol-buffers

Suppose `TextData` and `TextDataFields` are two protobuf messages, but `TextDataFields` is also a repeated field interleaved in `TextData`[^1]

This current code can compile:

```java
request.getTextData(0)
       .toBuilder()
       .setTextDataFields(0, request.getTextDataFields(0))
       .build()
```

However, on the 3rd line, since `TextDataFields` is repeated, there can be more than one or zero values. Currently the code only gets the first `TextDataFields` value and ignores the rest (And if there's none, it would have an index out of bound error)

My question is, how to modify the 3rd line to capture all the `TextDataFields`? So it would be something like

```java
request.getTextData(0)
       .toBuilder()
       .setTextDataFields(i, request.getTextDataFields(i) for i in range(0, request.getTextDataFieldsCount)))
       .build()
```

Maybe use `stream()` or `intstream()`?

Thanks!

---

[^1]: An example would be like:

```
message TextData {
  optional string id = 1;
  repeated TextDataField text_data_fields = 2;
}

message TextDataField {
  optional string id = 1
  ... # other fields
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use a for loop? You might have to split your statement but I don't see anything that prevents you from using a loop (I'm no expert on protobuf though, so I might miss something)

Comment: Is there a request.foreach() Method? Teen you could use request.foreach().getTextDataFields(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, I can simply use the "add all" function from Protobuf

```
request.getTextData(0)
       .toBuilder()
       .addAllTextDataFields(request.getTextDataFieldsList())
       .build()
```